# How to create Callback in Webservice for non-browser client?

Tags: web-services, google-api, google-api-client, webservices-client

An example is GoogleCL non-browser client as explained here :

http://www.maketecheasier.com/beginner-guide-googlecl/2010/06/23

> When you attempt to use the google command for a service for the first
>   time, it will open your web browser and ask you to authenticate it.
>   Click “grant access” and then press Enter back in the terminal window.

How Google webservice transfer data back to GoogleCL from the browser ?

I want to do the same kind of callback with my own webservice so I'd like to understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a Redirect URI of `http://localhost` and starting up a local webserver to wait for that redirect. See the code for the tools.run_flow() function in the Google API Python Client library that does this kind of flow:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/oauth2client/tools.py#110